# htaccess always remove .php but preserve query string (AJAX)

Tags: .htaccess

On a website I want to remove all .php file extensions from URLs for beautifying reasons.

Most of the RewriteRules I found on the web only rewrites from /site but not from /site.php to /site.

I solved this issue like this, which is working fine. If a user now types /site.php in to the browser it automatically rewrites it to /site. Great!

But now my Ajax isn't working anymore because the query string is not preserved neither on /site nor on /site.php.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

I tried adding the **?%1** to the first RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php?%1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

The Ajax call is working again but now /site.php remains /site.php.

How can I have both features in my RewriteCond?

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This will preserve query string.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a server error when using it this way.

Comment: Yes, but even if I copy your code without anything else in my htaccess file it isn't working.

Comment: Your existing code might be conflicting with these rules. btw these rules are working fine on my local Apache so there is no syntax issue here.

Comment: I deleted all my code for sure. I get this apache error: invalid HTTP response code '308' for flag 'R'

Comment: ok looks like you have slightly older Apacha that doesn't support `308`. I have made changes in rules to `301`. Can you retest updated rules.